# Meaning of factorization of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I am studying group theory from the book "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote, and in the text the author states the following:

> Simple groups, by definition, cannot be "factored" into pieces like $N$ and $G/N$ and
> as a result they play a role analogous to that of the primes in the arithmetic of $\mathbb{Z}$. This analogy is supported by a "unique factorization theorem" (for finite groups) which we now describe. 
>  
> Definition. In a group G a sequence of subgroups
> $$1 = N_0 \leq N_1 \leq N_2 \leq \cdots \leq N_{k-l} \leq N_k = G$$
> is called a composition series if $N_i \trianglelefteq N_{i+1}$ and $N_{i+1}/N_i$ a simple group.
> If the above sequence is a composition series, the quotient groups $N_{i+1}/N_{i}$ are called
> composition factors of $G$.

Can someone clarify to me what is the meaning of factorization here. for example, the author says that  $G$ factors into $N$ and $G/N$, and my understanding of factorization (from number theory) is that $G \cong N \times G/N$, but this isn't necessarily true since for example $Z_4$ isn't isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2$. So, my question is what does factors mean here and what are the significance of them.

Comment: There are too many mathematical concepts and not enough words. A factorization in this sense does not obey the exact same laws as a factorization in arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I just can't find any intuition of why would someone define something as specific as that (unless it has some importance that I don'e know of yet) and call it factorization.

Answer (score 1):

It just means you have a normal subgroup $N$ with quotient $G/N$.  Nothing more than that.

The pieces $N$ and $G/N$ are useful for studying $G$, even if you don't get anything as nice as $G \cong N \times G/N$.

Comment: So calling $N_{i+1}/N_{i}$ factors doesn't have any intuitive origin?

Comment: @HeshamAbdelgawad It does have an intuitive origin. You will eventually see the Jordan Holder Theorem which states that for any finite group, the isomorphism classes   showing up in a composition series and their respective multiplicities are uniquely determined, just like the prime factors of a number and their respective multiplicities are uniquely determined.

Comment: @Chris I got it thanks. May be, I will appreciate it more when I get more deep into the topic.